# Replace two rows in Mysql

Tags: php, mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

How I can replace everything from the base_amount and amount with the content of the base_real_amount in phpmyadmin.

[image]

Thanks

Comment: Please post code, errors, sample data or textual output here as plain-text, not as images that can be hard to read, can’t be copy-pasted to help test code or use in answers, and are hostile to those who use screen readers. You can edit your question to add the code in the body of your question. Use the `{}` button to format any blocks of code, or indent with four spaces for the same effect. We can’t run your screenshot as code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure how to do this in phpmyadmin so I apolgoize if this doesn't answer your question. To do this with just SQL:

```
UPDATE `table_name` SET base_amount=base_real_amount, amount=base_real_amount;
```

Comment: phpMyAdmin is just a front-end that allows you to run queries, so that query should do the job.

Comment: @Robert  you sure you want to update your entire table like that, without a WHERE clause? I might be wrong though.

Comment: yes is okay like this, I made the modification that I need there, thank you again

Comment: @Robert The question says you only want to replace 2 rows. Did you mean to say 2 columns?

Comment: One thing please Spencer Bard if you can help me with this too, if I want to change all values for one field, for example to change all values that is in the amount with 11 how I can do this?

Comment: Just to make sure I understand, you want to replace every row's amount with the number 11?

Answer (score 0):

Those aren't rows - they are columns. You could use a simple `update` statement to assign the value from one to the other:

```
UPDATE mytable
SET    base_real_amount = base_amount
```